# Mutiple Upload in Ajax request inside for loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Im having trouble in ajax for loop when I upload only 1 file, it's a success that only 1 file is uploaded.. But when I uploaded 2 file the response of upload becomes 4.. and when I upload 3 it gets 2x...

```
     for (var i = 0, file_name; file_name = dropzone.files[i]; i++) {

         $.ajax({
//THIS function ofr the progress of ajax call
          xhr: function() {
          var xhr = new window.XMLHttpRequest();
          xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress", function(evt) {

            if (evt.lengthComputable) {

              var percentComplete = evt.loaded / evt.total;
              percentComplete = parseInt(percentComplete * 100);

                      if (percentComplete === 100) {
                                $( "#spinner" ).hide();

                }

                else if (percentComplete !== 100){

               $( "#spinner" ).show();
                }

              }
            }, false);

            return xhr;


          },

           url: url,
           type: 'POST',
           data: file_name,
           processData: false,
           contentType: 'application/octet-stream',
           headers: {
           "Authorization": "Bearer ACCESSTOKEN",
           "Dropbox-API-Arg": '{"path": "/'+file_name.name+'", "mode": "add","autorename": true,"mute": false}'
           },



           success: function (data , response){

               console.log(data);

           },


          })




       }
```

Comment: what do you mean by `the response of upload`, and what does `2x` mean in the case of `upload 3` ?

Comment: when I uploaded 3 files and when I checked in my console log there a 9 files uploaded

Comment: 1 => 1 ... 2 => 4 ... 3 => 9 ... so, it's a progression of square numbers ... can't see why the code you posted would do that ... what is `dropzone.files.length` in each case? Perhaps some code regarding whatever that is is doing something wrong

Comment: when I dropzone.files.length it just said 2 if I uploaded 2 files

Comment: so, when there's 2 files, the length is 2, and when there's 3 is it 3?

Comment: Yes sir. I cant upload properly

Comment: usually you would do `for (var i = 0; i < dropzone.files.length; i++) {
    var file_name = dropzone.files[i];` - though I can't see why your code would loop through a "squared" number of times!

Comment: Should I put break? But when I put the break it only upload 1 file

Comment: can you console.log(i); at the top of the loop ..

Comment: It just said 01 if i upload 2 files

Comment: but you can see 4 uploads happening?

Comment: Yes when its success 4 uploads happening. But when its still uploading 2 files are uploading

Comment: maybe the problem can be server side, can you post the code please?